# mining Cryptonote currency on scrypt and sha-256 miner

Tags: cryptonote

I have a python [miner](https://github.com/ricmoo/nightminer) which is only capable of scrypt and sha-256 mining. Is it possible to mine cryptonote monero on it? Pool link(i use minergate): stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.  Monero uses the [Cryptonight](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/where-can-i-find-a-description-of-the-cryptonight-hash-algorithm) hash algorithm which is distinct from scrypt and sha-256.  However, you should be able to find other CPU mining implementations for this algorithm.  The place to ask would be https://monero.stackexchange.com.